# rtwintgt install

Tags: matlab

I type in Matlab command window `rtwintgt -install` and get the following error:

```
??? Undefined function or variable 'twintgt'. [sic]

» rtwintgt -install

You are going to install the Real-Time Windows Target kernel.
Do you want to proceed? [y] : y
??? Failed to copy the kernel to Windows system directory.
Access is denied.

Error in ==> C:\MATLABR11\toolbox\rtw\windows\private\rtwtinst.dll
Error in ==> C:\MATLABR11\toolbox\rtw\windows\rtwintgt.m (rtwt_setup)
On line 74  ==> reboot = rtwtinst('install', srcpath);

Error in ==> C:\MATLABR11\toolbox\rtw\windows\rtwintgt.m
On line 24  ==>     rtwt_setup
```

What should I do? And is it important to install this file?

My problem is when I call a matlab function from a file in my code using (@myfunction),
I get error?

Comment: Maybe its permissions problem. Do you have admin rights on the machine when you try to install the rtwt?

Comment: Aha.. I downloaded from my university.. I think they have open license. I will discuss this with them. Ok could you please tell me what could be wrong in calling a function from a file? it does not work with me. Thanks:)

Comment: Is this a different problem? Normally there isn't a problem calling a function from a script. What error does it give you?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Jorge. I just posted another question about this.

Comment: No need to thank anyone. Just upvote the answer and click it as "accept".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, check if you have admin rights on your machine as well as if your license includes the Real-Time Windows Target.